Torah fiction - dos and don'ts?
Is there a list of guidelines or rules about what is ok and what is not ok for an author to write fiction on, regarding Torah? E.g. assuming the author will be as faithful to the sources as possible:

Can an author write about a fictional Tzaddik, with detailed explanation of what made him a Tzaddik, what trails he went through, how he helped others with Ruach Hakodesh etc?
Can an author write, using authentic knowledge of Kabbalah etc. a novel about angels, or someone who goes into the Pardes etc?
Can an author write a super-hero story, that involves the Sefirot, angels, and other "spiritual forces" as part of the lore?
Can an author write a fictional story, but involving real personalities in Jewish history, including great Rabbonim in fictional circumstances?
Can an author ever have a Bat Kol or even Hashem as a "character" in the book, with fictional dialogue?

These questions are just illustrations, although feel free to answer any of them directly if you aren't able to produce a set of general principles or specific source to answer my question. Thank you.

The novel "As a Driven Leaf" is a beautiful way of tying together a lot of midrashic stories, and teach their lessons that way.

And what all the Midrashim, Talmudic Aggadetha, Kabbalistic allusions, and Hassidic stories are? Should we insist on their historicity?

Oh, you better write it in the name of a famous rabbi, preferably a Talmudic Tanna or a Kabbalistic figure. Or preface it with, I once heard an interesting story from a respected Hussid... :)


Can an author write about a fictional Tzaddik, with detailed explanation of what made him a Tzaddik, what trails he went through, how he helped others with Ruach Hakodesh etc

As Rav Sholom Schwadron once put it "I asked a shaalo if I can make up stories to give people inspiration and was told that if it inspires people I can do so ... and I  just told you   the first  story that  I made up..."

Can an author write, using authentic knowledge of Kabbalah etc. a novel about angels, or someone who goes into the Pardes etc? Can an author write a super-hero story, that involves the Sefirot, angels, and other "spiritual forces" as part of the lore

There is no way authentic knowledge of Kabbalah can be transmitted through a novel.

Can an author write a fictional story, but involving real personalities in Jewish history, including great Rabbonim in fictional circumstances

Unless the author is being clear that this is fiction how is it different than making up stories about anyone else?

Can an author ever have a Bat Kol or even Hashem as a "character" in the book, with fictional dialogue

NO! Being so anthropomorphic borders on heresy. Almost certainly on the wrong side of the border.
